# Finding a particulat file in Folder of sorted file

Tags: matlab

I have a folder which contain different files extension for example .txt, .xls.

The files are named in the following order:

- 20190228_0_20_20
- 20190228_50_20_50

I have sorted out all the files with the  .txt  extension. In this sorted folder, I would like to fine a particular file with the name 20190218_0_20_20 and load it and then  do some calculations. Here is my code.

Thanks very much in advance:

```
%processing the parent folder

myfolder ='C:\Users\yannick\Desktop\Windkanal_Data\Yannick';

if~isdir(myfolder)
    Error_message =sprintf('Error,Folder not found :\n %s',myfolder);
end

%Getting list of all files with  file pattern .txt

filepattern =fullfile(myfolder,'*.txt');

txtfiles=dir(filepattern);

%sorting out the file with name  20190228_0_20_20 .txt
```

Comment: If you already know the exact file name and path, why even search (dir) for it? Why not load it directly? Not sure what's the format of your txt file but you could try dlmread or importdata.

Comment: @Florian thanks am  just practice and its my pleasure to try different things around.i just want to deal with the complete fold rather than  single txt file. because for the rest of the other files i need to perform some calculation and then  make a plot. my file format is 20190228_50_20_20, just the last  two  numbers which are coordinate for x and y are changing.... thanks you

Comment: please i need  help on this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hm, we have to apply some pretty wild guessing what you are trying to do here, but I'll give it a shot:

```
% dir only those that match your format
filepattern =fullfile(myfolder,'20190228_0_*_*.txt'); 
% get all matching files
txtfiles=dir(filepattern);
% let's loop them
for iFile = 1:length(txtfiles)
    % extracting the x and y from the file name of the current file
    fn_parts = split(f(iFile).name,{'_','.'});
    coor_x = str2double(fn_parts{3});
    coor_y = str2double(fn_parts{4});
    % now you know the coordinates (x,y) that belong to the current file. You can use this to search for a specific coordinate if you like (though it would be easier to do this earlier I guess)
    % next step is reading it I guess. I have no idea about your file format. Try dlmread? importdata?
    fcontents = importdata(fullfile(f(iFile).folder,f(iFile).name)); 
    % process further...

end
```

Comment: Great, that's nice to hear. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: for each file i need to calulate 5 parameter each with dimension 15000x1 and then save this in a new txtfile bearing the  position of the coordinate.    Please  i need help

Comment: That is not a proper question. You really need to learn to ask questions in the right way. Start by reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask